# Let $f(x)=|x|+|x-1|$. Check the differentiability of $f$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f(x)=|x|+|x-1|$. Check the differentiability of $f$ at $x=0$ and
>   $x=1$

The short answer would be since $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ and $|x-1|$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, so $f(x)$ will not be differentiable at $x=0,1$ 
{Is it valid to claim this in every case ?}

Long answer:

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 - 2x & \text{ if } x< 0 \\ 1 & \text{ if } 0 \leq x < 1 \\ 2x -1 & \text{ if }x\geq1 \end{cases}$

$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}  = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1-1}{x-0} = 0$

$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1-2x}{x-0}=  -\infty$ is not finite. So not differentiable at 0

$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}= \lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{2(x-1)}{x-1} =2$

$\lim_{x \to  1^-}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1-1}{x-1}=0$

which are unequal and hence not differentiable at 1.

Is this proof fine ?

Comment: Small mistake: $\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1-2x - 1}{x-0}=  -2$ You forgot to actually subtract $f(0)$.

Comment: Without looking at the details, your $-\infty$ looks wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not fine:$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{1-2x-1}x=-2\neq-\infty.$$The rest is fine.

However, consider the functions $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=-|x|$. Neither of them is differentiable at $0$. However, their sum is. Do you see why I am writing this?

Answer (score 4):

Except for the mistake that I pointed out in a comment above, yes your long answer seems good. You've shown that $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ are different for the relevant $a$, and therefore $\lim_{x\to a}$ doesn't exist in either of those cases, and the function is by definition not differentiable.

Your short answer is flawed, however. Specifically, if you have a differentiable function $f$, and a non-differentiable function $g$, then the sum of $g$ and $(f-g)$ is differentiable. This construction works in general as a counterexample for several similar statements of the kind "the sum of two nice things is a nice thing implies that the sum of two non-nice things is a non-nice thing", like:

- The sum of two non-differentiable functions is non-differentiable
- The sum of two discontinuous functions is discontinuous
- The sum of two irrational numbers is irrational
- The sum of two transcendental numbers is transcendental

Comment: That last paragraph is so important. +1

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is almost right: since $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ **and $|x-1|$ is differentiable at $x=0$**, it follows that $f(x)$ can't be differentiable. This is because if it was, $|x|=f(x)-|x-1|$ would be the difference of two differentiable functions, so differentiable.

Your long version is good apart from a mistake in evaluating one of the limits (which should be $-2$ not $-\infty$).

Comment: Nice argument for short version.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get them by plotting the graph of the function. The function is non-differentiable at all sharp points and hence at $x=0,1$

[image: Graph of the function]

Comment: While a plot can be a great guide, it is never a proof. How do you _know_ that those corners aren't rounded if you just zoom in far enough? You can never prove that from a drawing alone.

Comment: Plots generally come extremely handy when dealing with differentiabilty of linear functions( and maybe in other higher order as well). This is useful here since each part is a line and lines meet at sharp points and never curves. Though I'd have to agree with you on more complex functions where plotting becomes difficult and you've to check with standard methods.

Comment: True. but you still have to prove at some point that linear functions meeting at an angle implies non-differentiability. And that this really is a case of linear functions (although that work was already done by the OP in this post). A plot won't do either of those things for you.